# TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'int'",),

Tags: python, iteration

I am trying to append a list using iteration but i keep getting the error. The problem is i need to use iteration to append a data into a list a number of specified times.

Here is the code:

```
def replicate_iter(times, data):
    result = []
    while times > 0:
        result.append(data)
        times -= 1
    return result
```

Comment: What does the call to replicate_iter look like? It looks like you are passing a list instead of an int for the "times" parameter

Comment: i am using a test driven development....According to your explanation it means there is a test to check whether my code can handle passing wrong values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are passing times as a `list` instead of a `int`.

```
def replicate_iter(times, data):
    result = []
    while times > 0:
        result.append(data)
        times -= 1
    return result
```

You might want to do something like this.

```
>>> times=2
>>> data=[10]
>>> replicate_iter(times,data)
[[10], [10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are making it complex. Just use this:

```
answer = [data]*times
```